# How to print proper minimum and maximum from user input

Tags: java, max, minimum

I am trying to write a program that allows a user to enter in a number of random grades they want to display along with the sum, average, minimum and maximum of the generated list. The grades range from 60 - 100.

The program is printing the min properly and the sum is adding up the previously generated sum along with the newly generated one. How can I change it so that it give the correct output for the minimum and so that is stops adding the previou sum to the new one? Any help would be appreciated.

The image link for the output shows the minimum output issue. The min should be 66.0 but it says 59.0.
  [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ull8B.png)
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class A03C
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many scores? ");
    int howMany = input.nextInt();

    double score = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    double max = 0;
    double min = 60;

    while (howMany > 0)
    {
       for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++)
       {
        score = 60 + (int)(Math.random() * ((100 - 60) +1));

        if (letterGrade(score));

        sum += score++;

        average = (sum/howMany);

        if (score > max)
               max = score;

        if (score < max)
               min = score;

       }
       System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
       System.out.println("Average: " + average);
       System.out.println("Max: " + (max - 1));
       System.out.println("Min: " + (min - 1));

       System.out.println("How many scores? ");
       howMany = input.nextInt();
    }

   }

    public static boolean letterGrade(double score)
    { 
       if (score >= 92.0) 
          System.out.println(score + " is an A");
       else if (score >= 83.0)
          System.out.println(score + " is a B"); 
       else if (score >= 75.0)
          System.out.println(score + " is a C");
       else 
          System.out.println(score + " is an F");
       return false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: "Having trouble" is a vague and uninformative problem description.  Please [edit] your question to include what the trouble is that you are having.  Are you getting compile errors?  Runtime errors?  Different output than expected? etc.  Please don't forget to include the *full text* of any errors you get, and the *expected* vs *actual* output when describing misbehavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean the sum variable after the execution, also I changed the return of the letterGrade to true:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A03C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many scores? ");
        int howMany = input.nextInt();

        double score = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double max = 0;
        double min = 60;

        while (howMany > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++) {
                score = 60 + (int) (Math.random() * ((100 - 60) + 1));

                if (letterGrade(score))
                    sum += score++;

                average = (sum / howMany);

                if (score > max)
                    max = score;

                if (score < max)
                    min = score;

            }
            System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
            System.out.println("Average: " + average);
            System.out.println("Max: " + (max - 1));
            System.out.println("Min: " + (min - 1));

            System.out.println("How many scores? ");

            sum = 0;

            howMany = input.nextInt();
        }

    }

    public static boolean letterGrade(double score) {
        if (score >= 92.0)
            System.out.println(score + " is an A");
        else if (score >= 83.0)
            System.out.println(score + " is a B");
        else if (score >= 75.0)
            System.out.println(score + " is a C");
        else
            System.out.println(score + " is an F");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before continue, i definitely think that you should read @joe C comment.
As i understand you are a beginner, i will explain the changes i did.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class A03C
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many scores? ");
    int howMany = = input.nextInt();

    double score = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    double max = 60;
    double min = 100;

    while (howMany > 0)
    {
       for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++)
       {
        score = 60 + (int)(Math.random() * ((100 - 60) +1));

        letterGrade(score);

        sum += score++;

        average = (sum/howMany);

        if (score > max)
               max = score;

        if (score < min)
               min = score;

       }
       System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
       System.out.println("Average: " + average);
       System.out.println("Max: " + (max - 1));
       System.out.println("Min: " + (min - 1));

       System.out.println("How many scores? ");
       howMany = input.nextInt();
    }

   }

    public static void letterGrade(double score)
    { 
       if (score >= 92.0) 
          System.out.println(score + " is an A");
       else if (score >= 83.0)
          System.out.println(score + " is a B"); 
       else if (score >= 75.0)
          System.out.println(score + " is a C");
       else 
          System.out.println(score + " is an F");
    }   
}
```

Starting with the function *letterGrade*. Since the function always return false and just prints a sentence, you can replace *boolean* to *void*.

Another mistake you did was that if you want to find *max* and *min*, the variables shall take the inverse of you want. So the variable max shall take the minimum variable (60) and the maximum value (100).

Finally, in order to change variables *max* and *min* you must compare the new value to their current value. This is, to change *min* value, for example, you have to compare *score* with current *min*.

Hope it helps.